# Burn MP4 to CD in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, burning, cd-image

I have an mp4 file (115,8 mb). I want to burn it to a Sony CD-R (700 mb) to watch on tv.
I tried to do it with DeVeDe from ubuntu software center but it always give me this error:
"Conversion failed. It seems a bug of Mencoder."
Can anyone tell me an other method to burn my mp4 to cd? Or can anyone tell me how to fix DeVeDe's error?

I use a TOSHIBA computer (64 bit) with windows 7 home premium and ubuntu 12.04 LTS (installed via wubi.exe).

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into DVDStyler. But I don't know if the file when converted to DVD will fit on a cd.

Choose the option to output to .iso first to see

Comment: Ok. I'll try it.

Comment: I solved the problem. :)

Comment: I do this: I tried DVD Styler but it doesn't worked for me so I opend DeVeDe, chose Video to DVD, changed 4,7 gb dvd to 700 mb cd, made the iso file, burnt it to cd and it worked. The only problem with this my 1 year old xbox360 slim can't play it but my old e:max dvd player play the video smoothy. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @xyc You should post it as an answer.